# ruby debugging: print line number when taking too long

Tags: ruby, profiling, benchmarking

Is there a way in Ruby to have it print the `__LINE__` number of code (at my script level, not required gems) it's working on if taking longer than 9 seconds (adjustable)?

For debugging I am getting it to print verbose output of what it's trying to do, where it is in the code etc., rather than silently sitting for long periods of time.

A flaky situation makes it unpredicable how far it gets before something times out, so successive advancing doesn't apply here.

EDIT

Something like a trap would work, such that:

- The original line number and hopefully code get remembered (both **benchmark** and **timeout** gems lose track of `__LINE__` for instance....  Maybe there is a way to push it off to another .rb file to manipulate the stack to include my file & line of interest?)
- When the overtime warning prints, execution still continues as if nothing had changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'timeout'

def do_something
  Timeout::timeout(9) do
    sleep 10
  end
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  puts "Something near line #{__LINE__} is taking too long!"
  # or, count backwards in method
  puts "Line #{__LINE__ - 5} is taking too long!"
end

do_something
```

This will stop execution if the timeout block runs out of time and raise a Timeout error.
If you want to continue execution, you might do better with benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

time = Benchmark.realtime do
  sleep 10
end
puts "Line #{__LINE__ - 2} is slow" if time > 9
```

One benchmark block can have multiple timers:

```
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report('sleeping:') { sleep 3 }
  b.report('chomping:') { " I eat whitespace ".chomp }
end
```

See more about benchmark here: 
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

If you want to keep track of the line number being executed, why don't you try passing it in to a custom method like so:

```
def timethis(line, &block)
  if Benchmark.realtime(&block) > 2
    puts "Line #{line} is slow"
  end
end

timethis(__LINE__) { sleep 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This could be useful. However the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) confirm `sleep 10` would get terminated and not be allowed to finish.  Know of a way to either not interrupt execution, or let it continue on after some debugging message gets printed?

Comment: @Marcos It does. If you don't want to interrupt the flow, you can try wrapping your code in a benchmark block instead. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Benchmark it is! Thanks. However I see `__LINE__` will get tainted to be that of the `puts` code, and my benchmark block would actually be 100's of lines of code.  But this puts me looking in the right direction.

Comment: @Marcos I added a bit about how you can have a lot of timers in one benchmark block so you can quickly spot the slowpokes.

Comment: @Marcos I added another example showing how you can create your own function to wrap Benchmark and keep track of the line number.

Comment: That is a good example of how to pass a code block as a param to my custom function (previous unfamiliar territory to me).  In my direction of thinking, every single line would have to be preceded with `timethis(__LINE__) {` and somehow all line-blocks still share in a common scope of variables etc.  Accepting till a better solution is found, now that I see this isn't trivial. Thanks!